# R6 class not recognized in S4 %*% method

Tags: r, r-s4, r6

I have an R6 class that I wish to have the `%*%` method defined. I have seen in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384772/inconsistency-of-s4-dispatch-behavior-for-r6-classes) how to accomplish this with a new S4 method.  However, I have tried this approach and it fails when I try to create the S4 `%*%` method for my R6 class.  For example:

```
library(R6)
setOldClass(c("TestR6", "R6"))
TestR6 <- R6Class("TestR6", public = list(.x = "numeric"))

setMethod("%*%", c(x = "TestR6", y = "TestR6"),
          function(x, y){
            print('the matmult operation')
          }
)

x <- TestR6$new()
y <- TestR6$new()

x %*% y
```

> Error in x %*% y : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

And yet, it still works if I create the `foo` method.

```
setGeneric("foo", signature = "x",
  def = function(x) standardGeneric("foo")
)
setMethod("foo", c(x = "R6"),
  definition = function(x) {
    "I'm the method for `R6`"
  })
try(foo(x = TestR6$new()))
[1] "I'm the method for `R6`"
```

Why doesn't it work for the `%*%` method?

Comment: The `%*%` doesn't seem to be marked as generic; it's primitive. Interesting. It [seems like it does check for S4 methods](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/8e191101cbd945650436bce628bf47cbd550a47e/src/main/array.c#L1215), maybe that's different for R6?

Comment: Look at the output `%*%`.  It calls a `.Primitive`, not `UseMethod`.  You \*can\* override this directly by assignment, however it's just a bad idea.  There was another thread about using `+` for string concatention that you can search for some ideas.

Comment: @thc do you have a link to that thread?

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730551/making-a-string-concatenation-operator-in-r

Comment: @MrFlick so does that mean with R6 classes, for primitives like `%*%`, `+`, and `-` I am basically SOL unless I want to 'override' functions?